# Receiving touch events on MKCircleView

Tags: mkmapview, mkoverlay, touch-event

I am trying to write an app where the user can click on an MKCircleView overlay on a map with several overlays (all of the same kind). Depending on which overlay the user clicks a specific message should be shown.

My first approach was to add a UITapGestureRecognizer in mapView that is provided by  mapView:viewForOverlay: but that didin't work.

Then I subclassed MKCircleView and implemented the following methods:

```
//subclassed to handle event when touches are received
- (void) actionWhenClicked {
    UIAlertView *a =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"It worked!"
                                               message:@"yeah"
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                     otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [a show];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self actionWhenClicked];

}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [self actionWhenClicked];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self actionWhenClicked];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [self actionWhenClicked];

}
```

Each of the overlays on the map is an instance of the above subclass and hence should respond when touched. But the methods are never called. I tried the same approach on a UIView where it worked. However, it does not work on the map with the overlays.

Any ideas?